# Java loop not creating string correctly

Tags: java, arrays, string, loops, for-loop

I'm using a for loop to append an "m" on to a string array, then passing each string to a DDE connection to download a stock quote.

```
    String[] symbols = {"AUDUSD", "EURUSD", "GBPUSD", "USDJPY"};

    String ibfxSym[] = new String[symbols.length];

    for(int i = 0; i<symbols.length;i++) {
        ibfxSym[i] = symbols[i] + "m";

    }
            // start DDE
    for (int i = 0; i < connections.length; i++) {
        try {
            connections[i].getQuote(ibfxSym[i]);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("error");
        }
```

That does not work, but if I pass in:

```
String[] ibfxSym = {"AUDUSDm", "EURUSDm", "GBPUSDm", "USDJPYm"};
```

instead of the loop it works just fine. I've tried printing each string as it is created in the loop, and they look the same. Is there some weird formatting the loop is adding that I can't see? I even tried:

```
ibfxSym[i] = String.valueOf(ibfxSym[i].trim());
```

to see if there was maybe a carriage return or something being appended that I couldn't see. Any ideas about what's going wrong here?
Thanks.

Comment: are you saying that after the loop, the ibfxSym[] array doesn't contain what you thought it would? There shouldn't be any carriage returns being appended, and the code seems correct, except for the getQuote(ibfxSym[i]) - is the number of connections the same as the array size?

Comment: Are you sure `connections.length` is the same as `ibfxSym.length`?

Comment: "That does not work" could be more specific.

Comment: What do you see when you debug your program line by line?  BTW: why do you discard any exception thrown, it may contain helpful information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not reading from the same array that you're modifying...

```
    ibfxSym[i] = symbols[i] + "m";

for (int i = 0; i < connections.length; i++) {
    try {
        connections[i].getQuote(ibfxSym[i]);
```

In other words, you are assuming that `i`, being derived from iterating over `connections`, is also a valid index for `ibfxSym`.

Comment: What? He's assigning to ibfxSym and calling getQuote on it as well.

Comment: @Kylar: The point @Falmarri is making is that the OP is creating `ibfxSym` and then iterating over it with an index derived from iterating over `connections`, which isn't safe unless you **know** they are the same length or if the former is smaller.

Comment: Ahh, that's not what he said. He's implying that he's printing from a different array, not a different index counter. I see what you're saying though.

Comment: The wording of this answer really confused me as well.

Comment: Actually @Kylar is right, I misread the code. But now the answer is that he didn't give us enough information.

Answer (score 2):

Your loop is working just fine, the connection loop instead would work only if your connections array maps your ibfxSym array though..

Answer (score 1):

if

```
connections.length
```

is bigger than

```
ibfxSym.length
```

or in this case 4, you should get an array index out of bounds exception i think.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to do this:

```
for(int i = 0; i<symbols.length;i++) {
    ibfxSym[i] = new String(symbols[i] + "m");

}
```

Comment: Calling a `String` constructor directly is redundant here.

Comment: Using + creates a new String, having a new new String shouldn't make much difference.

Comment: This happens under the hood already (sorta.. a stringbuffer actually gets used in both situations.)

Comment: I thought so, but wasn't sure when it came to arrays.